# ppx版のsexplibで旧来の<:sexp_of<型>>に相当するものはあるのでしょうか？

Tags: ocaml

新しいOCamlではCamlp4の代わりにppxが使われるようになり、[Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/data-serialization-with-s-expressions.html)にあるようなS式を取り扱うコードも一部適用できなくなったことを知りました。例えば`with sexp`の代わりに`[@@deriving sexp]`と書く、といった具合です。

```
# require "ppx_sexp_conv";;
# type some_type = { foo: int; bar: string } [@@deriving sexp];;
type some_type = { foo : int; bar : string; }
val some_type_of_sexp : Sexplib.Sexp.t -> some_type = <fun>
val sexp_of_some_type : some_type -> Sexplib.Sexp.t = <fun>
```

Camlp4の場合は他にも、無名の型に対して変換関数を生成する`<:sexp_of<型>>`という記法がありますが、これと同じものはppx版のsexplibにもあるのでしょうか？（また、ない場合は自前で書くことはできるでしょうか？）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `[%sexp_of: ty]`
- `[%of_sexp: ty]`

困ったことに現在 `deriving` 関連は

- `ppx_deriving`
- `ppx_type_conv` (Jane Street製)

の２つのライブラリがあります。この２つを混ぜる事は現在できなくなっています。(前はできたのですが)

`ppx_type_conv` 側に、 `ppx_deriving` での書き方、 `[%derive.sexp_of: ty]` とか `[%derive.of_sexp: ty]` は今のところありません。